# Broken drill bit is stuck in DeWalt drill

Tags: drill, stuck

I know this may be a common issue.

I have searched the internet and  so far i am not able to get this broken drill bit freed from my DeWalt drill .

My idea is trying to hammer this bit down but it is very tight I'm not sure I'll be able to.

Any ideas?

edit:
here's a video of what happens when I try to loosen it with a wrench:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/1cuyr79N5BPRCTg38

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: what happens when you try to loosen the chuck normally? are there weird noises? is it just hard?

Comment: While i am a fan of "get a bigger hammer"  a hammer is **NOT**  the tool you need here. Why do you think hitting it with a hammer will loosen the jaws of the chuck and where do you expect the broken bit to go if you hit it with a hammer? . You have to turn the chuck to loosen the jaws. **Do you know how to use the chuck on your drill?**

Comment: Ok i found a youtube video showing the hammer tap. "TAP". Ok i found a youtube video showing the hammer tap. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-z6izpCslFM  but it may not be what you need to do. We need more info from you.

Comment: Have you tried to tighten it a bit and then loosen it?  I have a drill with a ratcheting hand chuck and sometimes it gets into a weird state where I need to crank it tight a bit before anything else.

Comment: @depperm, yes, this is what happens:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/jKDLV37vRJDjohGs5

Comment: @AlaskaMan I know the bit which is stuck is about 1 inch form the tip we see in the picture, so if I hammer it enough it would fall inside out of those teeth... the problem is the execution.... about the video you put, I've seen it before, and tried that but it isn't as easy as the guy does in the video, it doesn't get any loose

Comment: @JPhi1618, I'll give it a try

Comment: If it has a clutch, make sure it is at max setting. Then, use your wrench but instead of turning it by hand (which it seems is just turning the gears and motor), clamp the drill in a vise and apply the wrench so it holds itself on, then strike the wrench a single sharp blow.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, sounds like a possible solution, since, yes, what I'm doing is turning the motor... I'll give it a try, thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove chuck with strap wrench (preferable -less chance of damage) or some large pliers (more likely to have on hand)?

e.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVYLLDW7ScE

Comment: I tried, once this happened in the past it worked, but now this is what happens:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/jKDLV37vRJDjohGs5

Comment: From your video it seems you have a double-sleeve chuck - from the latter part of the video I linked. This technique wont work in that case, im afraid.

Comment: You could try using a screw extractor (will need a very high quality one to bite into that bit) to get some grip so you can twist it out (some penetrating oil may help with that).